# Weird TwitterKit Timeline Profile Images Bug

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Profile image is weirdly large]

I've implemented the TwitterKit tweet timeline and for some tweets the profile image is very large and forgetting its aspect.

Is there a hack that fixes this? I've tried going through subclasses and ultimately got nowhere. The same thing goes to overriding the text size (as it's not a very friendly default size).

It also seems like there's not any support for TwitterKit or how to submit bug reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be fixed in the Twitter 2.5.0 update over the weekend.